# convert xlsx nested rows file to a json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

i have an **xslx** file with huge data contain nested rows like that:
[image]

i tried all online solutions, slsx-to-json npm for convert it to a nested json, but the result not as i want. Please if any one can help me.

would be appreciated.

what i want the data to be :

```
[
  {
      "MaterialName": "M-ACTIVATE B",
      "HSCode": 291811009999,
      "DescriptionInArabic": "حمض الهيدروكلوريك + كلوريد القصدير",
      "Chemical_extract": {
        "MaterialName": "HYDROCHLORIC ACID",
        "Name of material": "hydrochloric acid",
        "UN": "3264",
        "CASNo": "7647-01-0",
        "percentage": "20%"
      },
      "UsingInArabic": "مستحضر للإستخدام في صناعات السطح النهائي ولوحات الدوائر المطبوعة",
      "SupplierName": "MacDermid",
      "BySea": 1200,
      "ByAir": 300,
      "Total": 1500,
      "UOM": "لتر"
    },
...
```

not like this :

```
 {
      "Material Name": "M-ACTIVATE B",
      "HS Code": 291811009999,
      "Description In Arabic": "حمض الهيدروكلوريك + كلوريد القصدير",
      "Material Name": "HYDROCHLORIC ACID",
      "اسم المادة": "حمض الهيدروكلوريك",
      "الرقم الدولي UN": "3264",
      "CAS No": "7647-01-0",
      "النسبة المئوية": "20%",
      "Using In Arabic": "مستحضر للإستخدام في صناعات السطح النهائي ولوحات الدوائر المطبوعة",
      "Supplier Name": "MacDermid",
      "By Sea": 1200,
      "By Air": 300,
      "Total": 1500,
      "UOM": "لتر"
    },
```

Comment: It's impossible to help unless you show us some code. What code have you got already so we can look at it and help fix it?

Comment: @rmcsharry, no code just i'm used a converter website

Comment: Then stackoverflow cannot help you since this site is for programming help and you are not programming. Try Super User, where experienced Excel people might be able to assist.